# I am getting R Error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space how can i resolve this?

Tags: r, oracle, heap-memory, ojdbc, rjdbc

I am trying to execute a Oracle query having 1.5L rows in it and which is working completely fine in SQL developer.
I have even tried to increase heap size using below code

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx8g")
```

i have also tried using a garbage collector but still issue didn't resolve.
Below is my code snippet:

```
ABData<-data.frame(dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection, queryToRun),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

- jdbcConnection is Oracle connection object here i have used ojdbc6.jar for connection
- queryToRun is a SQL query

My system has 8Gb of RAM

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: R memory-management is a typical trouble for me, even when importing some xlsx files with `xlsx::` package.

    - Try several options to read your files, if you have several way of read your data. 

    - When importing is not allowed by R, the only solution I was able to manage is to suppress big objects in memory, with `rm(list = ls())` before the reading of my data, (sometimes it's necessary to keep a few objects, of course)